# How to control Navigation bar in UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: swift, navigation, navigationbar

I have one ViewController called X1.
ViewDidLoad is as below:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never

    navigationItem.title = "Output Details"

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "iconBack_58"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "PDF", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(generatePDF))

    collectionView?.register(CategoryCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
}
```

If I click at top right button, it will run the function generatePDF.

the purpose is to open pdf file once I click on generatePDF file.

```
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
        let pdfURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: tmpPDFPath)
        let interactionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: pdfURL)
        interactionController.delegate = self

        interactionController.presentPreview(animated: true)

    })
```

PDF file opened properly, but I am not able to control the navigationBar color.
once newcontroller is opened, if first show me on the left top side of navigation bar "Output Details" (in viewDidLoad) but immediately changed to back.

How can I control the navigation bar so I can change the color to black, cause whatever I do, it remains white.